# Defiining a background in strings.xml

Tags: android, android-button

In android generally for buttons having different 
"background" are stored in a xml file inside the drawable folder, whereas the "style" for text on that button is stored in the strings.xml file? Why is that so?
Can the strings.xml also contain the button backgground details(It's color, shape etc), Or is that purely the work of Selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTW...`styles` are not supposed to be stored in the `strings.xml`. Instead, they should be in `styles.xml` under `values` folder. The reason to do this is to have clear distinction between different type of objects. This will help when you are going to support multi-lingual (as only `strings.xml` need to be modified in that case).

For reference:

[Resources Group](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes)

Comment: But somehow it also works when the style attribute is added to the strings.xml and referred to as "@style/ButtonText. I don't understand why this works as there is no style.xml file.

Comment: Technically it will work...as it is under `resources` tag. Its just a convention you need to follow. You can actually have different names for xml too. But in the end its convention...just like good design patterns...